# Launch an app using intent and continue from where user has left it

Tags: android, android-intent

I developing an android app in which I want to launch an third party app and i managed to do it using Intents

```
Intent i=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("Your package name");
startActivity(i);
```

and it works properly,but I want to launch an app not as a new task ,it should be launched and resumed on the state where the user has left it.I have tried using set flags method but it didn't worked!!
Any solution,Thanks in advance..

Comment: even after clearing it from recent applications ??

Comment: No when the app is running in recent application

Comment: then you can use `saveInstanceState` : for saving your state & `restoreInstantState` : for restoring your state..!!

Comment: OK thanks I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Either the app can save its internal state on your request, and launch with state restoration. You need to find related documentation.
Otherwise, I fear it is practically impossible.
Saving the state from outside involve saving the whole process including OS resources in use. And relaunch with restoration means exact process restoration, including OS resources, which can be pretty complicated and almost impossible.